# How to avoid error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to build a scraper for Linkedin Jobs. I have been getting errors again and again because I am having difficulty in parsing links out of HTML files.

Here's the code I have written:

```
page_source=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
job_card = page_source.find_all('div', class_='base-card relative w-full hover:no-underline focus:no-underline base-card--link base-search-card base-search-card--link job-search-card')
for job in job_card:
    job_title= job.find('h3',class_='base-search-card__title').text.replace(' ','')
    job_company_name = job.find('h4',class_='base-search-card__subtitle').text.replace(' ','')
    job_link_post = job.find('href',class_='base-card__full-link absolute top-0 right-0 bottom-0 left-0 p-0 z-[2]').text.replace(' ','')
   
    print(f'Title = {job_title}\n'
        f'Company Name = {job_company_name}\n'
        f'Job Link = {job_link_post}\n')
```

I know I can't parse HTML with text, but I have tried several ways still I am getting this error. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much!

**EDIT**

Sharing a screenshot of the href class I am using:[image: Link to Screenshot]

Comment: That means it's not finding what you're looking for.

Comment: are you sure the element tag and class names are correct and they exist? note that if you see it on inspect element, doesn't mean it always exists in html, sometimes they're loaded with ajax. ~try ctrl-u on the page and search for the content there. if you're new i'd suggest you use selenium for now, because capturing and parsing ajax requests might take a little bit of skill~ just realized you're using a webdriver already. it's also possible that your code is running before the content is loaded, try putting `time.sleep(5)` before `page_source=..`

Comment: One of your `.find` calls is not finding what it's looking for and returning `None` instead. You need to break those statements into two and handle that case

Comment: I am adding a screenshot for reference. I am pretty sure I am using the right class name - [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILOjV.png)

Answer (score 1):

One of your `.find()` calls is not finding what it's looking for and returning `None` instead. You need to break those statements into two and handle that case, like this:

```
    elem = job.find('h3',class_='base-search-card__title')
    if elem is not None:
        job_title = elem.text.replace(' ','')
    else:
        # handle or report the error
        raise ValueError(f"Could not find job title in {job}")
```

Depending on the situation, you might do various other things in the `else` clause, such as using a placeholder value:

```
        job_title = '[unknown]'
```

or skipping the entry and continuing with the next one:

```
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Main issue is that you try to find the link by attribute and not by tag:

```
job.find('href',class_='base-card__full-link absolute top-0 right-0 bottom-0 left-0 p-0 z-[2]')
```

That wont work that way and will result  in `None`, instead use:

```
job.a.get('href)
```

**There are also some other points you should be aware:**

- Try to select your elements more specific and use `id` and HTML structure instead of chaining classes.
- Check if an element you try to find is available before calling methods.
- Do not use `replace()` in case of stripping, instead use `.get_text(strip=True)`

##### Example

```
for job in soup.select('.jobs-search__results-list li'):
    job_title= job.h3.get_text(strip=True) if job.h3 else None
    job_company_name = job.h4.get_text(strip=True) if job.h4 else None
    job_link_post = job.a.get('href') if job.a else None
    print(f'Title = {job_title}\n'
        f'Company Name = {job_company_name}\n'
        f'Job Link = {job_link_post}\n')
```